# Numba doesn't significantly accelerate recursive binary search

Tags: python, numpy, binary-search, jit, numba

The following code performs a recursive binary search over a one-dimensional numpy array of boolean values, looking for change in (true/false) state and noting the index of the array at which these changes happen.

For every change, the algorithm will output something equivalent to:

- the index before the change happens
- the index when the change happens
- the type of change happening (before-becomes-true, when-becomes-true, and so on)

It does so by detecting large spans of consecutive values (checking with the very fast implementation of `numpy.all()` / `numpy.any()` and skip them, in a recursive binary-search manner, up until there are only 2 or 3 non-consecutive elements in the smallest chunks.

```py
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def binary_search(arr, start, end):
    void = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    if arr[start:end].all() or not arr[start:end].any():
        return void + void
    elif arr[start:end].any():
        if end - start == 2:
            one = arr[start]
            two = arr[start+1]
            c = [one, two]
            if c == [False, True]:
                return [start, -2, start+1, -1] + void
            elif c == [True, False]:
                return [start, 1, start+1, 2] + void
        elif end - start == 3:
            one = arr[start]
            two = arr[start+1]
            three = arr[start+2]
            c = [one, two, three]
            if c == [True, True, False]:
                return [start+1, 1, start+2, 2] + void
            elif c == [True, False, False]:
                return [start, 1, start+1, 2] + void
            elif c == [False, True, True]:
                return [start, -2, start+1, -1] + void
            elif c == [False, False, True]:
                return [start+1, -2, start+2, -1] + void
            elif c == [False, True, False]:
                return [start, -2, start+1, -1, start+1, 1, start+2, 2]
            elif c == [True, False, True]:
                return [start, 1, start+1, 2, start+1, -2, start+2, -1]

        else:
            mid = start + (end - start) // 2
            left = binary_search(arr, start, mid)
            right = binary_search(arr, mid-1, end)
            return left + right
```

I've been using this code on the following sample generated data (made of large spans of consecutive true/false values, which is representative of the real data):

```py
positions = np.zeros(shape=300000, dtype=np.bool)

positions[0:748] = True
positions[1305:3281] = True
positions[10938:12389] = True
positions[18392:23819] = True
positions[35884:36728] = True
positions[44847:45238] = True
# ... and so on until the end
```

On this sample data (300k rows), the pure-Python (not `@jit`) version of `binary_search()` consistently runs in about 11ms. The Numba version (with `@jit` and post-compilation) consistently runs in about 5ms.

The difference between Numba and non-Numba is not even of an order of magnitude, here. I've been used to differences up to the order of 100x, leading to microseconds delays when the pure-Python version was around 11ms. I find it very surprising that in this case, Numba is not capable of performing better.

Is there a reason why my code isn't particularly accelerated by Numba? Is it because an improper use of recursion? Is it because I'm using raw Python `lists` to return values between recursive calls? (and in this case, is there a way to do otherwise?)

A purely iterative version of this function (iterative in the concept, not only the implementation) where we simply loop through every element of `arr` and compare it with the previous one and the next one, noting the index where changes happen, runs MUCH faster than this recursive binary search when using `@jit` (becomes even truer as the array grows in size). I'm not sure to understand why this happens, as intuitively I would say the binary search method should perform in O(log n) instead of O(n) for the iterative method.

--
Note: Numba doesn't complain about `binary_search` when using `@jit(nopython=True)`

Comment: arr[start:end].all() looks more O(N) rather O(1). Maybe slowdown comes frome it.

Comment: that was exactly that — I posted a simpler version of this question here which had more success than this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372395/why-numba-doesnt-improve-this-recursive-function

Comment: I was naively assuming that `.all()` on boolean values would be O(1) as it's a `bitwise_or` essentially, but I was obviously mistaken